# Using local project installs (also called editable installs) with root user

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Using git submodules I put the library `my-pkg` into a subfolder of my scripts. In `my-pkg` there is a valid package structure for a package `my_pkg`.

```
my-pkg/
├─ setup.cfg
├─ setup.py
├─ my_pkg
|  ├─ __init__.py
...
```

It is possible to `pip install -e my-pkg` when not using the root user (in a testing environment where it is possible to use other users). How can I debug or solve this for the root user in the target environment?

There is no error message, the only feedback is:

```
Installing collected packages: my-pkg
  Running setup.py develop for my-pkg
Successfully installed my-pkg
```

The statement has no effect when using the root user. When using the statement with other users, `my-pkg` becomes importable.

It is possible there are other differences between the environment where the local project install works and where it doesn't. But the user thing is the most obvious. Everything else runs with all versions and files fixed using Docker.

Some additional information:

- version of setuptools (I tried several other as well): 65.6.3
- It does not make a difference if `python -m pip` or absolute paths are used for pip or python3

Comment: run `pip freeze ` as root and see if the package is in the list of installed packages

Comment: The package does not show up in `pip freeze` and `pip list`

Comment: It works when using the --user flag: `pip install -e my-pkg --user`

Comment: Most probably, the pip used by the root context and and the user level are different.  Did you create a venv and try ?

Comment: No, the `--user` workaround was sufficient for my use-case